# listview inside recyclerView dont scroll

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-recyclerview

i have a list view inside a recyclerview like this:
[image]

and scrolling of listview doesnt work on this implementation.

my goal is when clicking on button the listview toggle to show and hide. 
the main Ui is on viewpager for tab

```
   public class tabOne extends Fragment {

    RecyclerView myTabRecycler;
    adapterMainList adapter;

    public tabOne() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_one, container, false);

        myTabRecycler = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.tabRC);
        myTabRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(G.context);
        llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        myTabRecycler.setLayoutManager(llm);
        adapter = new adapterMainList(Utiles.getSampleCat());
        myTabRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
        Utiles.Log(Utiles.getSampleCat().size());
        myTabRecycler.startNestedScroll(2);

        return v;
    }
    }
```

the adapter for recyclerView:

```
 public class adapterMainList extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<adapterMainList.CatViewHolder> {

    private List<retroCategory> cats;

    public adapterMainList(List<retroCategory> catList) {
        this.cats = catList;

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return cats.size();
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final CatViewHolder catViewHolder, final int position) {


        final retroCategory cat = cats.get(position);
        Utiles.Log("BindNow");
    }

    @Override
    public CatViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.
                from(viewGroup.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.adapter_item_category, viewGroup, false);
        return new CatViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    public static class CatViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        protected ListView vList;
        protected ImageView vImg;


        public CatViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);

            vList = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.adapter_item_list);
            vImg = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.adapter_item_img);

        }


    }
    }
```

the item Ui:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/adapter_item_cat_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
        card_view:cardElevation="4dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                        android:id="@+id/adapter_item_num_session"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="4dp"
                        android:gravity="left|bottom"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/adapter_item_img"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.3"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/sherlock" />


            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/adapter_item_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp">

    </ListView>




</LinearLayout>
```

and on runnig app when i want to scroll the listview, RecyclerView Scrolled instead of that ... how can i fix That??
thanks

sorry for bad english

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **should not use** a `ListView` inside another scrollable view.
In this case you are using a ListView inside a RecyclerView.

Use a LinearLayout instead of the ListView.
Something like:

```
public class MyListLayout extends LinearLayout implements
        View.OnClickListener {

    private Adapter list;
    private View.OnClickListener mListener;

    public MyListLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyListLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    }

    public MyListLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mListener!=null)
            mListener.onClick(v);
    }

    public void setList(Adapter list) {
        this.list = list;

        //Popolute list
        if (this.list!=null){
            for (int i=0;i<this.list.getCount();i++){
                View item= list.getView(i, null,null);
                this.addView(item);
            }
        }

    }

    public void setmListener(View.OnClickListener mListener) {
        this.mListener = mListener;
    }
}
```