# ListView Inside a RecyclerView

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I am creating a listview inside a Recyclerview. I am populating Recyclerview with data which is fetched online. The RecyclerView is populating properly. I want to populate the listview at the run time when a button will be clicked. I am defining onClickListener for the button and on button click I am getting the data and populating an adapter which will be set to the listview. But the data is not reflecting in the listview.

[image]

onClickListener for the Button

```
 holder.arrow_up.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                new LoadClothes().execute(order.getOrderId());
        }
    });
```

Asynctask for Loading details for listview

```
 private class LoadClothes extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String string = "";
        try {
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(ORDERCLOTHES)
                    .addHeader("token", BaseApplication.getToken())
                    .addHeader("orderId", strings[0])
                    .build();
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            string = response.body().string();
            Logger.d(string);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return string;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String string) {
        super.onPostExecute(string);

        Logger.d(string);

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type type = new TypeToken<List<OrderedCloth>>() {
        }.getType();
        cloths = gson.fromJson(string, type);
        viewHolder.listView.setVisibility(ListView.VISIBLE);
        CustomListOrderAdapter adapter = new CustomListOrderAdapter(context, cloths);
        viewHolder.listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Here you can try from this link, [try this link ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34665381/listview-inside-recyclerview-dont-scroll)

Comment: Here you can try from this link, try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34665381/listview-inside-recyclerview-dont-scroll

Comment: Thank you for your effort,But that is totally a  different question.I am initializing the listview adapter at run time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you want to do that? That seems like a design pattern problem. If you are going to show additional data fetched with an HTTP request, a better way to do it could be another activity with the details.

However, **I think the problem is the "viewHolder"**, where are you getting that variable?

A simple way to solve it seems like passing the ListView to the AsyncTask:

```
private class LoadClothes extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private ListView listView;

    public LoadCloathes(ListView listView) {
        this.listView = listView;
    }

    //...

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String string) {
        super.onPostExecute(string);
        //mostly the same but
        //make sure somehow listview is still available
        listView.setAdapter...
    }
}
```

Then run the AsyncTask:

```
new LoadClothes(listView).execute(order.getOrderId());
```

As you can see an AsyncTask can take params in the constructor, the arguments in the `execute()` method are to support the AsyncTask cycle, but is still a Java class.

Comment: Thank You. It worked like a charm. But I am not getting why passing listview through constructor is working but a class variable of listview could not work.

Comment: Because of the Recycler.Adapter will literally recycle the ViewHolder, so it will re-use it for another row, then you don't know where the view actually ended. Take a quick test by adding a log in the onCreate and then in the onBind methods, you will see sometimes the onCreate log won't be, but the onBind log will. That is because this adapter create a pool of views, if it can spare memory by taken a view rescuing one of those views instead of inflating a new one, it will, it will recycle it (that is the performance improvement compare with the ListView Adapter)

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to do that.
Just make a recycler view and inside it make a LinearLayout with orientation "vertical" instead of a listView.
Now in the OnBindViewHolder of the recyclerView just run a loop till list.size() and keep inflating the view in linearLayout with addView(). Before the for loop just removeAllView().
This will work and won't make the scrolling a bad experience.